# OrderBy a relation in an entity

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I've got a headache :) Been trying to google this for an hour, and before that trying to solve it for an hour.

I've got an entity A with a ManyToOne relation to another entity B. I need to sort a select of A by one of B's parameters.

i.e. $qb->addOrderBy('p.dogShowClass.weight', 'ASC')

I'm lost. Help! :)
I will be monitoring this closely, if you need *any* further details, please do write and I will get it to you ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->join('p.dogShowClass', 'd')
    ->orderBy('d.weight', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
;
```

Comment: Seems to have done the trick! Too much data for me to verify, but i've asked someone else to verify it. So far, good job!